# Firestore query with multiple where clauses based on parameters

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I want to query a Firestore database with multiple where clauses based on the parameters that are passed in. The following block of code works:

```
getProducts2(accountId: string, manufacturer?: string, materialType?: string): Promise<Product[]> {
  return new Promise<Product[]>((resolve, reject) => {
    const productCollection2: AngularFirestoreCollection<FreightRule> = this.afs.collection('products');

    const query = productCollection2.ref
      .where('materialType', '==', materialType)
      .where('manufacturer', '==', manufacturer);

    query.get().then(querySnapshot => {
      if (querySnapshot.size > 0) {
        const data = querySnapshot.docs.map(documentSnapshot => {
          return documentSnapshot.data();
        }) as Product[];
        resolve(data);
      } //todo else...
    });
  });
}
```

But what I really want to do is conditionally include the where clauses based on the optional parameters. The following is what I want, but it doesn't work:

```
getProducts2(accountId: string, manufacturer?: string, materialType?: string): Promise<Product[]> {
  return new Promise<Product[]>((resolve, reject) => {
    const productCollection2: AngularFirestoreCollection<FreightRule> = this.afs.collection('products');

    const query = productCollection2.ref;
    if (manufacturer) {
      query.where('manufacturer', '==', manufacturer);
    }
    if (materialType) {
      query.where('materialType', '==', materialType);
    }

    query.get().then(querySnapshot => {
      if (querySnapshot.size > 0) {
        const data = querySnapshot.docs.map(documentSnapshot => {
          return documentSnapshot.data();
        }) as Product[];
        resolve(data);
      } //todo else...
    });
  });
}
```

While valid, this code just returns all of the products with no filtering.

Is there a way to structure this so I can filter based on the optional parameters?

edit: I realize I can do something like:

```
let query;
if (manufacturer && materialType) {
  query = productCollection2.ref.where(....).where(....)
} else if (manufacturer) {
  query = productCollection2.ref.where(....)
} else if (materialType) {
  query = productCollection2.ref.where(....)
}
```

I was just hoping for something a little more elegant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build upon the prior query, don't repeat the prior query:

```
let query = collection  // initial query, no filters
if (condition1) {
    // add a filter for condition1
    query = query.where(...)
}
if (condition2) {
    // add a filter for condition2
    query = query.where(...)
}
// etc
```

Comment: Got it, thank you. I needed to assign query.where to query.

Comment: This really helped! I was looking for something similar to \u2731 which would be * and in sql matches "any". But this solution works as well.

Comment: this answer is perfect, it helps me on android too.... i was trying to filter data without any good result until i saw this answer.. thanks stackoverflow for existing

Comment: Doug, I tried query = query.where(...) and get IntelliSense error "Property 'where' does not exist on type 'AngularFirestoreCollection<abc>'".  Any idea why it's not working?

Comment: @JimBistis If you have a question, you should post it separately with a full explanation of what isn't working the way you expect with your code.

Comment: How to do it in Android??

Answer (score 0):

If using different query structure, You can try below ways:

```
db.collection("subscriptions").where("email", '==', req.body.email,"&&","subscription_type","==","free").get();
```

OR

```
db.collection("subscriptions").where("email", '==', req.body.email).where("subscription_type", '==', 'free111').get();
```